# How I can use selected language for uninstaller?

Tags: dialog, nsis, uninstallation

I have my `.nsi` with this configuration:

```
#########################################################################
## Language Selection Dialog Settings

## Remember the installer language
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "HKCU"
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\${APP_COMPANY}\${APP_PRODUCT}"
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Installer Language"

## Languages (first language is the default language)
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Dutch"


## Language selection functions (for install and uninstall)
Function .onInit
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd

## Uninstaller Functions
Function un.onInit
   !insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
FunctionEnd
```

But when I try to uninstall the uninstaller shows me the language dialog everytime.

I follow the MUI2 README and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry value specified by MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_* is saved automatically by MUI on the MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES page. If you are not using this page then you can call the MUI_LANGDLL_SAVELANGUAGE macro yourself or manually write the value of $LANGUAGE.

I would recommend just using the MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES page so everything is taken care of for you:

```
!define APP_COMPANY "Foo"
!define APP_PRODUCT "Bar"
!include MUI2.nsh
InstallDir "$Temp\Test"
RequestExecutionLevel user

#########################################################################
## Language Selection Dialog Settings

## Remember the installer language
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT HKCU
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\${APP_COMPANY}\${APP_PRODUCT}"
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Installer Language"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES


## Languages (first language is the default language)
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Dutch"


## Language selection functions (for install and uninstall)
Function .onInit
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd

## Uninstaller Functions
Function un.onInit
   !insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
FunctionEnd

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\${APP_COMPANY}\${APP_PRODUCT}"
DeleteRegKey /IfEmpty HKCU "Software\${APP_COMPANY}"
Delete "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
RMDir $InstDir
SectionEnd
```

Comment: thanks, I had worked on the OP's test case and did not found why the registry keys was never written. Good to know.

Comment: @Anders I have MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES but the uninstaller show's me the language dialog...

Comment: @JorgeB. Then why is it missing from your example code? It worked when I tried it. Are you using NSIS v3 or v2.46?

Comment: I solve my problem changing the MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_* to before of MUI_PAGE_*. Thaks for the help.